# php : get file contents and store file in particular folder

Tags: php, file

I am getting file contents from the `file_get_contents()` function in php and I want to store that file in a particular folder.  How would I do that?

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://www.affiliatewindow.com/logos/1961/logo.gif');
```

I want to save this image in particular folder.

any idea about it?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use [file_put_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://www.affiliatewindow.com/logos/1961/logo.gif');
file_put_contents('./myDir/myFile.gif', $image);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using php 5, you can use `file_put_contents`:

`file_put_contents('/path/to/file.dat', $data);`

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the mentioned file_put_contents, you could take a look at the example of the [`fwrite` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).