# Creating file from query with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm working on a Project for pedestrian navigation. For blind people, I'd like to tell them if there are any objects in the same street as they are, so they can orientate themselves.

I have a Json-file full with coordinates of trees from a city. I query geonames (with $.ajax) to get the nearby streets of the trees and want to store this information in a file. A json-file would be great, but I have no idea how to do this.

Can anyone tell me how I can create such a file? It has to be made only once.

Or do you know an alternative to store the data in a better way?

What I tried so far in js:

```
function writeToJson(streetNames){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "scripts/treeStreets.php",
    data: streetNames,
    dataType: 'json',
    error : function(parameters){
        console.log("error");
        console.log(parameters);
    },
    success:  function(){
        console.log("success");
    }
});
}
```

And the php-script:

```
$streetNames = $_POST[streetNames];
file_put_contents('/live%20access/data/treeText.txt', $streetNames);
```

But this gives me an error.

Comment: I think JS has no easy functionality for saving local files. Why don't u use a simple PHP call to get the data and save it to a file or a database?

Comment: @Petra I would if I knew how. Can you give me an example or do you know a good tutorial for this?

Comment: Very simple example found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729143/php-get-file-content-and-store-file-in-particular-folder

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a service in a language like PHP, Ruby, Python or Java. JavaScript has no ability to create a file on either the client or server so you'll need a service that the AJAX operation can call which will write the data to disk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me how to call a service in an ajax operation? I guess I have to pass the data that I want to write in the file, right?